# Libgdx, sprite batch and setColor to specific region

Tags: libgdx, textures, spritebatch

So I have a simple texture: one big green circle in the center and one small white circle also in the center of my texture. And now I want to change color of my white circle to yellow in my app. Is it possible and what is the best way to set color of my batch for specific region? I saw it is possible in other engines using the second texture with marked region which color will be changed.

Like that:
http://s9.postimg.org/qh7bbu5an/FINAL.png

1. My original texture
2. 2nd texture with region which color i want to change
3. The result of my texture in app which will be working like batch.setcolor but only for specific region (pixels) in my texture

Comment: Another thing, what is the functionality of this red/white circle, is just a flag, that indicates some setting or state in you application?

Comment: I figured out what I want to achieve :D. I need a mask. So the second texture is my mask, and the first one is an input texture. First I render my first texture without mask region and then I render my mask region from the first texture with custom color of batch. The question remains, how to achieve this :/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an example of masking textures together, you can check this tutorial.

https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/ShaderLesson4

It also has a port to libGDX.

Comment: I understood, but my goal is to add color for specific region in my texture. For example: instead of green circle I have image1 and instead of white circle i have image2 but it's black and white and now I want to change color of my image2 for example to yellow. This won't work :/

Comment: I see, why is it important to have only one texture object?

Comment: I have many textures on my asset collection (like 3000) and I just want to decrease number of another textures :)

Comment: Use then TextureRegion, with texture packer you can pack your textures into one big, and this way only one object will be loaded not 3000. Did you try this solution?

Comment: Unfortunately yes :/
TextureRegion is very good solution for small number of textures. I just don't want to kill my RAM because whole textureRegion will be in my memory (I've check it) and I want to use my own texture package format in future :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103089/discussion-between-garos-and-dragomirus).